# Installing mod_fastcgi on Apache 2.4.4?

Tags: apache-http-server, fastcgi

I'm trying to set up a specific environment and one of the requirements for it is the FastCGI module for Apache. However, to the best of my knowledge, httpd and some other files are deprecated as of 2.4.4.

Let's say I have apache2 installed in `/etc/apache2`. From within mod_fcgi2.4.6 dir:

`make top_dir=/etc/apache2/`

To which it responds:

```
Makefile:12: /etc/apache2/build/special.mk: No such file or directory 
make: *** No rule to make target '/etc/apache2/build/special.mk'. Stop.
```

Hence, it tries to look for a file which I do not have (and is not created during the apache installation!).

Any pointers as to what I could possibly do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this but I'll go ahead and answer it just in case anyone else might run into it. The solution to this ended up being compiling Apache 2.2 from source and then installing FastCGI. For some reason I had issues with compiling 2.4.4 however, but 2.2 worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

in `Makefile` change variable `top_dir` to `/usr/share/apache2`